# Visualforce apex form not saving records

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I created a basic VF page with an apex:form component however when I preview it and enter details, the record is not saved in my org. The same happens when I add the component to a community - is there something I am missing?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <h1>Enter Account</h1>
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Account">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Name}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Phone}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! Account.Industry}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: add a `pageMessages` component to surface any errors

Comment: No. I don't receive any errors; the page just reloads as if it saves but the account isn't in my instance..

Comment: did you add the `pageMessages` component?

Comment: Thanks added and it saves! Required fields were hidden and did not put <apex:inputField> for them